# stdout and stderr not going into file when using unbuffered shell redirection?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a script that runs indefinitely on a raspberry pi. I use rc.local to run it at startup. I have some errors that only appear after hours or days of running the script. I wanted to capture output and errors to a logfile to review after an error so I implemented these options at startup.

```
python3 -u /home/pi/Documents/Python\ Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temp_controller.py &>> /home/pi/Documents/Python\ Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temps\ files/logfile.txt &
```

The file logfile.txt is created, but no data is ever put in it. I would expect this when the file is buffered and never closed, but in this case any print or error should appear immediately. Right?

This also imports other modules I have written, and some I have not. Any stderr or stdout from those will be redirected as well, correct?

Comment: You've done nothing to change the buffering.  ( `&>>` is unspecified behavior, so perhaps the shell you are using does actually change the buffering, but it's impossible to say)

Comment: As I understand it the -u before the script name should enable python unbuffered. The "&>>" must have been a mistake by me. I guess I read an extra ">" when looking at the Shell redirection documentation.

Comment: I was going to drop a comment that it ought to parse as `&` putting the command into background and terminating it, and `>>` just starting a new command that would nondestructively create the target if empty, but append nothing if it exists...then I decided to test it first, just to be thorough. On my git bash emulation, this construct is capturing both stdin and stdout to the target log. WTF?

Comment: @PaulHodges Does your script terminate? My script is meant to run until someone pulls the power cord or terminates the process manually.

Comment: I didn't bother to make a script. I just used the command line construct with `date` (which put the date in the log) and `foo` (which reported that no such program exists...to the log.)

Comment: Hmm. That's frustrating that it's working for you and not me. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong though. I'm quite inexperienced with both Linux and Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `nohup`.

```
nohup python3 -u '/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temp_controller.py' >> '/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temps files/logfile.txt' 2>&1 &
```

I quoted the paths rather than backquoting just the embedded spaces. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I'll study your syntax so I know how to do this in the future. If the script crashes due to some error, this should capture that as well, correct?

Comment: Yep. `2>&1` means send stderr to wherever stdout is going. It's probably not even needed with nohup, but I prefer to be explicit. The `&` at the end throws the whole thing into background.